# Binding issue in a list at a complex model to an mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new using .NET MVC Web Application. I'm using the version 4 of Web Application.
I'm developing a page to manage the roles of the simple membership provider, and I want to it be dynamically. To clear what I mean, it would be something like this:

[image: UsersInRoles]

Something really simple as that. To do so, I have a complex ViewModel such as this:

```
public class UserInRolesModel
{
    public List<string> AllRoleNames { get; set; }
    public List<UserInRoles> UsersInRoles { get; set; }

    public UserInRolesModel()
    {
        AllRoleNames = new List<string>();
        UsersInRoles = new List<UserInRoles>();
    }

    public UserInRolesModel(List<string> allRoleNames, List<UserInRoles> usersInRoles)
    {
        AllRoleNames = allRoleNames;
        UsersInRoles = usersInRoles;
    }
}

public class UserInRoles
{
    public UserInRoles(string user, List<string> userRoles, IEnumerable<string> allRoleNames)
    {
        User = user;
        Roles = SetRoles(userRoles, allRoleNames);
    }

    private List<bool> SetRoles(List<string> userRoles, IEnumerable<string> allRoleNames)
    {
        return allRoleNames.Select(userRoles.Contains).ToList();
    }

    public string User { get; set; }
    public List<bool> Roles { get; set; }

    public void UpdateRoles(List<string> allRoleNames)
    {
        var roleProvider = (SimpleRoleProvider)System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider;

        var rolesAdded = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Roles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Roles[i])
            {
                rolesAdded.Add(allRoleNames[i]);
            }
        }
        roleProvider.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { User }, rolesAdded.ToArray());
    }
}
```

In my View, I have something like this to display the role names:

```
<th><strong>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AllRoleNames, "AllRoleNames")</strong></th>
```

And, I have a DisplayTemplates Folder, with the AllRoleNames.cshtml file in it, and here is what's inside (I'm not worried about the layout of the page yet):

```
@model List<string>

@if (Model != null)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i])
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i])
    } 
}
```

So far, so good. It displays the name correctly.
But, when I try to press the Save button, the MVC should get the proper names from the html to bind to object Model in my HTTP Post Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdminUsers(UserInRolesModel model)
{
    //code to save roles goes here
    return View(model);
}
```

But I get an empty model. (I'm just worried to the list of roles name for now, because once I figure out what's happening with it, I can also figure out what's happening with my list of UserInRoles object).

I could find out why the MVC is not binding correctly. It's because the html generated is something like this:

```
<input id="AllRoleNames__0_" name="AllRoleNames.[0]" type="hidden" value="Admin">
Admin
<input id="AllRoleNames__1_" name="AllRoleNames.[1]" type="hidden" value="Extrator">
Extrator
```

The name attribute is being generated as "AllRoleNames.[0]" when it should be "AllRoleNames[0]". There is an extra dot there. So, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294466/asp-net-mvc-3-not-binding-collections-to-models-on-posting) with a hack proposed by the answer. It could work, but when I tested, I saw that my HtmlFieldPrefix already was without the dot, so of course it didn't work.

My question is, why is MVC generating these names with the dots, and is there a way to tell it to generate it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that passing a List as the model is nothing but pain.  If you pass a class that contains the List life becomes much easier.  You can then use a for loop and things will start behaving the way you expect them to.  i.e.

```
for(int i = 0; i < model.MyList.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyList[i])
    @Html.DisplayFor(model  => model.MyList[i])
}
```

should yield your property names correctly.

Comment: Indeed, PITaylor, I didn't have a good result working with a list at the model. So, with your answer, I figured out that I could work with everything in my view, without needing a DisplayTemplate. So, I just used something like @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AllRoleNames[i]) inside a for loop as you suggested. Also, I used the same logic to display CheckBoxes for the user permissions. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Not a problem...I had to learn this for myself the hard way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thats occur because you are using a `for` cycle instead of a `foreach`, try with this in the `AllRoleNames` template:

```
foreach (var role in Model)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => role)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => role)
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniele, thank you for your reply. Indeed, when I tried to use a foreach statement, I got rid of that dot. But it also get rid of my collection, because the code generated is something like "AllRoleNames.role" for all items. Do you see that I lose the [0], [1] on my list? So, when I post back, it doesn't bind to the model either. I appreciate your answer, but it didn't work...